# Bash : Replace entire line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am using the following line to get the line number in which a specific string occurs :

```
nLine=$(awk '/text/{ print NR; exit }' $1)
echo "line = $nline"
```

returns :

```
line = 78
```

Now, I would like to replace this specific line with an other string by using :

```
awk 'NR==$nLine {$0="new text $2"} 1' test.xml
```

Where $2 is a param given to the bash script.

This command line works fine when it is enter directly into the terminal or when I put the parameter as :

```
awk 'NR==78 {$0="new text data"} 1' test.xml
```

but it never works as expected when parameters are given to the command..

In addition, is it possible to avoid the print in the terminal ? Because when I put > /dev/null at the end of the line nothing appends.

Comment: pass bash variables to awk using `-v` parameter.

Comment: It works for the first parameter if I use awk -v line=$nLine 'NR==line.. But it seems not work for the second one. Indeed. awk -v line=$nLine second=$2 'NR==line {$0="new text second"} 1' test.xml does not work as expected.

Comment: Have you tried `awk -v line=$nLine -v second=$2 'NR==line {$0="new text " second} 1' test.xml`? Anyway, the answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863518/bash-inexplicable-behavior-sed) probably makes this question needless.

Answer (score 0):

That makes no sense. Just replace it when you find it:

```
awk -v nText="$2" '/text/{$0="new text " nText} 1' test.xml
```

---

ASIDE: wrt use of ENVIRON as discussed below, consider this:

```
$ foo='a\tb'
$ printf '%s\n' "$foo"
a\tb
$ awk -v foo="$foo" 'BEGIN{ print foo }'
a       b
$ foo="$foo" awk 'BEGIN{ print ENVIRON["foo"] }'
a\tb
```

So, ENVIRON is better if you don't want the escape sequence expanded but it does require more code and it is less efficient if you need the value of `foo` multiple times, e.g. in a loop (in which case you'd use even more code and more duplication of the word `foo`: `foo="$foo" awk 'BEGIN{ foo=ENVIRON["foo"]; print foo }'`.)

Now, let's try it when the value you're interested in is stored in a positional parameter instead of a shell variable. Following the pattern we seem to be showing above, that would be:

```
$ set -- 'a\tb'
$ printf '%s\n' "$1"
a\tb
$ awk -v foo="$1" 'BEGIN{ print foo }'
a       b
$ 1="$1" awk 'BEGIN{ print ENVIRON["1"] }'
-bash: 1=a\tb: command not found
```

Of course that doesn't work and the subtle thing you need to be aware of is that the name of the shell variable for the shell assignment that occurs before teh call to awk can't always be the name of the shell variable you want to get the value of as that might not even be a variable you can assign to:

```
$ foo="$1" awk 'BEGIN{ print ENVIRON["foo"] }'
a\tb
```

An alternative that works in all cases is to specify the variable value in the argument list:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ foo=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""; print foo }' "$1"
a\tb
```

but that has caveats too as you can then no longer simply loop through ARGV to get the names of your input files.

Now, lets compare the very realistic evolution possibilities of 2 scripts, one using `-v` and one `ENVIRON`:

```
$ awk -v var=100000000 'BEGIN{ print var }'
100000000

$ var=100000000 awk 'BEGIN{ print ENVIRON["var"] }'
100000000
```

Now, let's say we want to use `var` as the end value for a loop. Here's the 3rd attempt timings:

```
$ time awk -v var=100000000 'BEGIN{ for (i=1;i<=var;i++) i }'
real    0m7.813s
user    0m7.706s
sys     0m0.031s

$ time var=100000000 awk 'BEGIN{ for (i=1;i<=ENVIRON["var"];i++) i }'
real    0m11.673s
user    0m11.637s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Note how much less efficient the ENVIRON version is.

Alternatively, what if you just need to use it a couple of times in the script:

```
$ awk -v var=100000000 'BEGIN{ print var; if (var > 5) var = 5; print var }'
100000000
5

$ var=100000000 awk 'BEGIN{ print ENVIRON["var"]; if (ENVIRON["var"] > 5) ENVIRON["var"] = 5; print ENVIRON["var"] }'
100000000
5
```

Note how much less concise the code for the ENVIRON version is.

In both of the above cases then you wouldn't really want to use ENVIRON["var"] other than to init an awk variable and then use that in the rest of the code:

```
$ time var=100000000 awk 'BEGIN{ var=ENVIRON["var"]; for (i=1;i<=var;i++) i }' 
real    0m7.692s
user    0m7.612s
sys     0m0.031s

$ var=100000000 awk 'BEGIN{ var=ENVIRON["var"]; print var; if (var > 5) var = 5; print var }'
100000000
5
```

so unless you want to have to rewrite your code as it evolves, if you are going to use ENVIRON then the equivalent of:

```
awk -v var=val 'BEGIN{ print var }'
```

is not

```
var=val awk 'BEGIN{ print ENVIRON["var"] }'
```

but instead is:

```
var=val awk 'BEGIN{ var=ENVIRON["var"]; print var }'
```

which is lengthy and repetitious at best compared to using `-v`.

Something else to consider is that when you are parsing a file and each record is separated by a newline (assume that's not the default) would you want to write:

```
awk -v RS='\n' '1'
```

or

```
awk -v RS="$'\n'" '1'
```

to set RS to a newline? The former is, of course, much more convenient and intuitively obvious and you certainly don't want to have to write:

```
RS="$'\n'" awk 'BEGIN{ RS=ENVIRON["RS"] } 1'
```

What about FS being a tab:

```
awk -v FS='\t' '{print NF}'
```

vs

```
FS="$'\t'" awk 'BEGIN{ FS=ENVIRON["FS"] } {print NF}'
```

The point is - expanding the escapes is almost always the desired effect so writing lengthier, slower, more cumbersome code that disables that effect would not be a good default way of writing your code.

IMHO - just use `-v` unless you don't want escape sequences expanded and don't want to escape them in the assignment (most commonly when the value you are assigning from is stored in a shell variable as in the above example):

```
$ awk -v foo='a\tb' 'BEGIN{ print foo }'
a       b
$ awk -v foo='a\\tb' 'BEGIN{ print foo }'
a\tb
```

Final thought - I consistently tell people when writing shell loops to by default use:

```
while IFS= read -r var
do
      whatever
done
```

In particular I'm saying to use `read -r var` by default to stop escapes being expanded in the shell variable while in awk I'm saying use `awk -v var=` to cause escapes to be expanded in the awk variable.

The reason for the apparent inconsistency is that shell is a tool to manipulate files and processes and sequence calls to other tools while awk is a tool for manipulating text.

If you assign a shell variable in a loop it should be a loop on file names, for example, and so it's critically important not to expand escapes or the resultant variable will NOT contain the name of the file as intended.

If you assign an awk variable then it's got something to do with manipulating text and the most common thing is that the text contains literal tabs, newlines, etc. NOT that the text contains literal `\t`s and `\n`s so by awk expanding `FS='\t'` to `FS=<a literal tab>` that IS the behavior you want for parsing a file of tab-separated values.

So unless you have a specific reason otherwise - do not write shell variable initializing code to expand escapes because that's probably not what you want given what shell is used for, and do write awk variable initializing code to expand escapes because that probably is what you want given what awk is used for.

Comment: You should pass `$shell_var` to `awk` through environment variable like `nText=$2 awk '/text/{$0="new text " ENVIRON["nText"]};1'`. Using `-v var="$shell_var"`, `awk` will expand escaped sequences in `$shell_var`. Also note using `;1` for POSIX compliant.

Comment: See: http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226 for the requirement about `;`. `ENVIRON` is required by POSIX and nawk does have it. AFAICT, I only see `oawk` from heirloom tools chest doesn't have it. Also note that that variable only available through `awk` session, it gone after awk end.

Comment: It doesn't allow `'/x/{print} {print}'`, meaning you must insert the `;` to make it valid `awk` statement. There's a chance to find a POSIX `awk` implementation broken if missing `;`. Adding `;` never break any existing script, since when it's the valid form by grammar. I don't see the efficient here? In this case, how can you passing the literal `\t`? Using `-v var` will expand it to tab, why `ENVIRON` don't. Using `-v var` to get external input is not reliable.

Comment: Quick comment: `env "1=$1" awk 'BEGIN{ printf "%s\n",ENVIRON["1"] }'` works.

Comment: @EdMorton: It's not clutter your code, it made your code legal POSIX and 100% never broken. For `$shell_var`, I invite you to read http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113799/38906

Comment: It is 100% never broken as-is, just like the millions of other scripts that don't put useless semi-colons after action blocks. Even `gawk --lint` won't complain about it, never mind `gawk --posix`. Why would I want to read that article?

Comment: Im deleting all my ENVIRON comments here to tidy up.

Comment: Another note that assigning to positional argument is allow in `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

For replacing line(s) you can either use

> Sed or Awk

Specify the line number in sed or NR (number of record) in awk as shown in the example below

> awk 'NR==34 { sub("AAA", "BBB") }'

or use FNR (file number record) if you want to specify more than one file on the command line.

> awk 'FNR==34 { sub("AAA", "BBB") }

'
or

> sed '34s/AAA/BBB/'

You can use variables for replacement as well using the $ sign1