# bash : inexplicable behavior sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I wrote a quite simple bash script as :

```
#!/bin/bash

nLine=$(awk '/text_to_parse/{ print NR; exit }' testFile.xml)
echo "LINE = $nLine"
sed -e "${nLine}s/.*/new text/" < testFile.xml
echo 
cat testFile.xml

exit 0
```

the execution returns :

```
LINE = 8
<Test>
    <Name>First Test</Name>
    <Version>1.0</Version>        
    <Command>new text</Command>
</Test>

<Test>
    <Name>First Test</Name>
    <Version>1.0</Version>        
    <Command>text_to_parse</Command>
</Test>
```

The modification is never applied. The file can be modified ..

```
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  290 Jan  1 00:23 testFile.xml
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your `xml` and your shell script? `LINE` should be 4, and that `sed` call of yours should replace the whole line rather than just `text_to_parse`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your whole script should be rewritten as this one command:

```
sed -i 's/.*text_to_parse.*/new text/' testFile.xml
cat testFile.xml
```

You'll need to provide a param to `-i` in some seds.

Comment: From OP's output I think that they just want to replace `text_to_parse` and not what's around it.

Comment: Maybe, idk as they didn't provide sample input and expected output so I just rewrote their shell script as a sed script. They probably want something completely different - it's always hard to guess what a script should do from reading a script that doesn't do what they want it to do!

Comment: You are right Ed. Thank for your response. I will take your remark in account if I have to post new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure how is Line = 8. But then if i understand the requirement correctly, it is to replace the first line that has the text. You can also do the below:
`sed -i '/text_to_parse/{s/.*/new text/;:a;n;ba}' testFile.xml` OR
`sed -i '0,/text_to_parse/{/text_to_parse/s/.*/new text/}' testFile.xml`